# How can I use NTLM SSPI authentication with aiohttp?

Tags: aiohttp

[How to use Python requests to perform NTLM SSPI authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407946/how-to-use-python-requests-to-perform-ntlm-sspi-authentication) describes how to use the requests-negotiate-sspi package with the requests package for NTLM SSPI authentication.  Is there a package that provides similar functionality that I can use it with the aiohttp package for asynchronous HTTP requests on a Windows domain?