# How to download from sharepoint with authentication?

Tags: python, http, sharepoint, download, upload

I have been trying to download a .csv file from sharepoint via python, but failed. I am doing the following which I found in an answer in stackoverflow.

```
# Access sharepoint
csv = requests.get(url="https://foobar/testbook.xlsx", data={}, auth=(email, pass))
my_df = pandas.read_csv(StringIO(csv.text))
print(my_df)
```

The above prints:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [403 FORBIDDEN]
Index: []
```

There's no error in the output so I guess my authentication fails? I am searching for a way to download/upload files from/to sharepoint, with authentication.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint usually uses NTLM authentication while the "auth" parameter in requests is short for basic authentication.

Try using ntlm authentication as explained here:
[How to use Python requests to perform NTLM SSPI authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407946/how-to-use-python-requests-to-perform-ntlm-sspi-authentication/40422758)

Answer (score 0):

First register your application using [this methodology](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51982.sharepoint-read-online-list-data-from-c-console-application-using-access-token.aspx)

Once you have collected client id and secret.

Then use [this method](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/tree/master/examples/sharepoint/files) to download file via Office365-REST-Python-Client

after authenticating

```
client_credentials = ClientCredential('{client_id}','{client_secret}')
ctx = ClientContext('{url}').with_credentials(client_credentials)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this python package and its class called SharePoint.

You can find it on Github using the following link:

https://github.com/Tax-Justice-Network/tjn_tools

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).