# REST post request with API key and Windows login credentials

Tags: python, c#, rest, python-requests

I am trying to replicate what this C# code for a REST API post with requests in python.

```
public static string SendData(string request, bool bIsJson,string apiKey)
{

    var sMediaTYpe = bIsJson ? "application/json" : "application/xml";
    var sResponse = System.String.Empty;
    using (var c = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() {UseDefaultCredentials = true}))
    {
        c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ApiKey", apiKey);
        var task =  c.PostAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GatewayRestUrl"],
          new StringContent(request, Encoding.UTF8, sMediaTYpe));
        Task.WaitAll(task);
        var responseTask = task.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Task.WaitAll(responseTask);
        sResponse = responseTask.Result;
    }
    return sResponse;

}
```

From what I understand, this sends the windows login credentials *and* an API key that I have. I cannot figure out how to replicate this in python

This is what I have so far, but I am getting 401 responses

```
import requests
import getpass

restURL = 'url'
method = "post"
headers = {'ApiKey': 'key'}
username = getpass.getuser()

response = requests.request(method, restURL, headers=headers, auth=(username,getpass.getpass()), verify=False, json=params)
```

Comment: There is no username and password in the C# code

Comment: Probably a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407946/how-to-use-python-requests-to-perform-ntlm-sspi-authentication - you're trying to do NTLM passthrough.

Comment: @OneCricketeer from what I gather from google, "UseDefaultCredentials = true" will "if requested by the server, requests will be authenticated using the credentials of the currently logged on user". I don't need something as automated as that. I'm just trying to find out how to pass through the active directory username and password (even if they are manually entered) and an API key.

Comment: I don't know C# HTTPClient library too well, but I believe that is referring to the HTTP session credentials, like a Cookie, not the OS credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to @wkl. Seems it was a duplicate.

If anyone in the future finds this question I was able to use the requests_negotiate_sspi package to perform the windows credential auth.

```
import requests
from requests_negotiate_sspi import HttpNegotiateAuth

response = requests.request(method, restURL, headers=headers, auth=HttpNegotiateAuth(), verify=False, json=params)
```