# How to use request.get() with defaultCredentials in python?

Tags: python, python-requests, httprequest, windows-authentication

I am using the below code to get html from a URL using VB.NET

```
Dim strURL As String = "https://abcdef.com/page.aspx"
Dim strOutput As String = ""
Dim wrResponse As WebResponse
Dim wrRequest As WebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(strURL)
wrRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = True
wrResponse = wrRequest.GetResponse()
```

I wanted to implement the same functionality in Python :

```
import requests
x = requests.get('https://abcdef.com/page.aspx',verify=False)
print(x.text)
```

But I get this reponse:

```
  <h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>
  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied. 
  </h3>
```

This is not working, since the site needs credentials. How can I include my default credentials in tht request? In all the solutions i have seen, people are hardcoding the username and password.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34991883/authorise-with-current-user-credentials-for-python-script-accessing-sharepoint-l ??

Comment: The first code block is `VB.net` and not `C#`!

Comment: Don't it say VB.NET?